# KOMA-Script: How to style the title of a chapter

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script

How does one apply a custom styling to the chaptertitle in KOMA-Script? I know about the existence of the titlesec package but I've read that it doesn't play very well with KOMA-Script which outputs a warning. Therefore my idea was to style the chapter page soley with the help of KOMA-Script functionality.

I've read some posts about styling chapters and came up with the following code:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}
% centering the chapter head
\let\raggedchapter\centering

\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\normalsize\mdseries}

% This block has the two variables \chapapp and \thechapter. But where
% can I find a variable for the title of the chapter (eg. \chaptertile) to apply some styling? 
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \MakeUppercase{\chapapp}~\thechapter\\[-0.6\baselineskip]
    \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
        \rule{0.9\textwidth}{.5pt}%
    }%
}

% If I use this line for styling the title of the chapter - I get an error
% \addtokomafont{chapter}{\MakeUppercase}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=8\baselineskip]{chapter}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Using `\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}` does work for styling the `\chapapp~\thechapter` which correctly outputs "Chapter 1". What I have not found is a variable similar to `\chapapp` or `\thechapter` which holds the chapter title and can be used to style the title, like assigning uppercase a.s.o.

I have found `\addtokomafont{chapter}{}` but somehow this is not working with the `MakeUppercase` makro.

My question would be if a similar command to `\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}` exists where I can access a variable for the chaptertitle?

Comment: The line with MakeUppercase mainly throws an error because there is a brace too much. But there was indeed a bug in an older version. I don't really know what you are looking for with the header, but i think package `scrlayer-scrpage` will help you.

Comment: What exactly do you want to have uppercased? And where is this line supposed to appear?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, the brace was too much, sorry for that. My plan was to make the chapter title uppercase. `MakeUppercase` still throws an error even without the useless brace removed. The title should appear under the line but in uppercase letters. I hope that explains it somehow.

Comment: The chapterformat alone gives me errors. Commenting that out, does it work? Do you have an up to date KOMA? There was a bug in some previous version on just that topic.

Comment: Strange, this works on my machine. Also this sharelatex code https://de.sharelatex.com/project/555f3af03b14e98f7d561e0f seems to work

Comment: The commands that influence the font of the chapter naturally also influence the chapterformat, this all boils down to `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\centering\MakeUppercase{something\\else}
\end{document}
` The recommenden interface for this would be `chapterheadmidvskip`, but currently this is also uder the influence of the command. I informed the author.

Comment: Thank you so much, Johannes! I have the latest version installed, `2015/05/19 v3.18.2106 KOMA-Script package`.

Comment: Oh, very up to date, nice :-) Cross-link http://komascript.de/node/1926

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Second update**

Here is a new and in my opinion better suggestion that needs [KOMA-Script Version 3.19 or newer](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script). In version 3.19 there is a new command `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` that could be redefined to use `\MakeUppercase` for the chapter titles.

```
\documentclass[english]{scrreprt}[2015/09/29]% needs version 3.19 or newer
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=8\baselineskip]{chapter}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\normalsize\mdseries}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot%
  \IfUsePrefixLine{%
    \par\nobreak\vspace{-\parskip}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}%
    \rule{0.9\textwidth}{.5pt}%
  }{\enskip}%
}

\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \MakeUppercase{#2#3}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter One}
\textbf{\KOMAScriptVersion}
\par
\Blindtext
\addchap{Chapter without number}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Note: If you also want to use `\MakeUppercase` without the option `chapterprefix=true` you have to redefine the command `\chapterlinesformat`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \@hangfrom{#2}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
}
\makeatother
```

---

**Update**

My original answer (see below) works with both MiKTeX2.9 and TL 2015 but not with 2014 (but you can load `fixltx2e` to get it to work as @Johannes mentioned in a comment). So here is another suggestion.

```
\documentclass[english]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}
\newif\ifmakeupper
\newcommand*\chaptertitleformat[1]{\ifmakeupper\MakeUppercase{#1}\else#1\fi}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\makeuppertrue}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\normalsize\mdseries}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \MakeUppercase{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}\thechapter\autodot%
    \IfUsePrefixLine{%
      \par\nobreak\vspace{-\parskip}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}%
      \rule{0.9\textwidth}{.5pt}%
    }{\enskip}%
}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=8\baselineskip]{chapter}

\renewcaptionname{english}{\contentsname}{\chaptertitleformat{Contents}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{\chaptertitleformat{Chapter One}}
\textbf{\KOMAScriptVersion}
\par
\Blindtext
\addchap{\chaptertitleformat{Chapter without number}}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Note, you have to redefine `\tablename`, `\listfigurename`, `\listtablename`, ... so that they use `\chaptertitleformat` and you have to insert this in all `\chapter` commands. But as an advantage now there is only a switch in the `\addtokomafont` command.

[image]

---

**Original answer** (does not work with Version 3.19)

Here is a suggestion but note that `\MakeUppercase` inside `\setkomafont` or `\addtokomafont` can be problematic. In any case `\MakeUppercase` have to be the last command added to the komafont of a fontelement because it needs an argument.

```
\documentclass[english]{scrreprt}[2015/02/07]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\MakeUppercase}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\normalsize\mdseries}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \chapapp~\thechapter%
    \par\nobreak\vspace{-\parskip}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}%
    \rule{0.9\textwidth}{.5pt}%
}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=8\baselineskip]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I actually patched `chapterformat` as suggested by Markus :-) Too late. +1

Comment: Hello @esdd, thank you for your solution. Somehow this code still throws and error with the message:

 `(./test.aux) (./test.toc) [1{/home/hetsch/.texlive2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdft
ex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Chapter 1.
! Use of \@rule doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \def 
                
l.19 \blinddocument`

If your solution works for you and the and @Johannes_B, I might have something totally messed up on my local pc. I have to check that out and afterwords I'm happy to accept your answer. Thank you so far!

Comment: On my local pc there is still a problem with \MakeUppercase. If I comment out `\addtokomafont{chapter}{\MakeUppercase}` everything compiles fine Without the error message from the comment above.

Comment: I haven't actually tried out your code, i know your skills with KOMA-script. But i actually get the same error as in my own tests, the same that was already mentioned on the linked post to komascript.de. `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{ test \rule{5cm}{1cm} test}
\end{document}` <- But this is fixed with the new Kernel.

Comment: I have tested the code yesterday with KOMA Script versions 3.16 and 3.18.2106 on both MiKTeX 2.9 and TL 2015. There it works. Today I have used TL 2014 and I got the same errors as you. I will change my answer.

Comment: You could have just used `fixltx2e` ;-)

Comment: @esdd: Thank you million times for all the fiddling around! It seems to work now!

Comment: @Johannes_B: Importing `fixltx2e` did the trick with the older version of esdd's example. And yes, my latex skills are pretty limited right now so I had no idea before what you mean with Kernel :)

Once again, thank you both for your help! I wish I could accept two answers ...

Comment: @Johannes_B  Yes, `fixltx2e` is also a possibilty. Thank you for the hint. But in the new answer there is no `\MakeUppercase` in the `\addtokomafont` command ...

Comment: @esdd: If I use your newest code in the top of your post, it too centers the and uppercases the "ACRONYM" headline while "BIBLIOGRAPHY" is aligned left with uppercase (using glossary and biblatex package). This is not the case with the ToC and LoF headline. I think this behaviour has to do with `\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}` centering all chapter headlines. Do you think that it is possible to apply these formating only to numbered chapters as for example 1. Introduction, 2. Main Body aso?

Comment: @esdd: Do you think that it is possible that the chapter prefix like "chapter 1" is in small caps while the chapter title as "Introduction" is uppercase?

Comment: @esdd: Nevermind, I have now found a solution to my problem (https://gist.github.com/hetsch/74b1e19c45970f4be5f0).

Answer (score 4):

A bit alternative approach:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\let\raggedchapter\centering

\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\normalsize\mdseries}
\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadmidvskip}{%
    \par\nobreak\vskip -.1cm {\rule{.9\textwidth}{.5pt}}\par%
}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=8\baselineskip]{chapter}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\tracingpatches
\xpatchcmd{\@@makeschapterhead}{%for the unnumbered
    \usekomafont{chapter}{#1}\par
}{%
    \usekomafont{chapter}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}\par
}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@@makechapterhead}{%for numbered
    \usekomafont{chapter}{#1}\par
}{%
    \usekomafont{chapter}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}\par
}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \mbox{\MakeUppercase{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}\thechapter\autodot
    \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter*{Bussy Baboon}
\chapter{walzing Wombat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution than my suggestions.

Comment: @esdd Using the new kernel, there is no need to patch anything. Nevertheless, this feels quite *patchy*.

Comment: Indeed, this approach makes it easy to apply different styles to the chapter elements. This was somehow part of my original question. If you don't mind @esdd, I accept this one as my favourite answer.

Comment: @hetsch This is the very patchy approach. Markus stated, that the font switches are for font changes, which `\MakeUppercase` is not and it should be treated within `chapterformat`. Haking the chapterhead-command feels wrong, to be honest. As KOMA is growing more and more complex, the quick and dirty *patch it* approach will be impossible.

Comment: @Johannes_B: True words. But can you think of another way, where it would be possible to separately style the chaptertile (Walzing Wombat) via `\xpatchcmd{\@@makechapterhead}` and the chapterprefix (Chapter 1) formatted via `\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}`. I'm thinking about applying `\MakeUppercase{\textls{#1}}` to the chaptertitle. My appologies if I'm terribly missing something!

Comment: komafont{chapter} applies to the prefix and the prefix, the prefix being a subset. If you use chapter-> textls, you probably have to use `\setkomafont{\normalfont}` to have it non spaced. On the other hand, all-caps stuff isn't very nice to look at, and you are completely right, that it needs spacing. Have you considered using small-caps along with package `microtype`? The result ought to be better than that.