# Simple control of koma headings

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

When using `koma`'s `twolinechapter`,
how do I control the first and second line?

I'd like to:

1. Make the word *Chapter* all uppercase.
2. Reduce the vspacing between [*Chapter #*] and the [*section title*].
3. Center the [*section title*]. (Only the first line centers.)

   - Possible solution: `\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering}`

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\KOMAoptions{
           % headings      = small,
           % headings      = openany,
             parskip       = half-,
             headings      = twolinechapter}

\doublespacing

\setkomafont{chapter}      {\normalsize}
\setkomafont{section}      {\normalsize}
\setkomafont{subsection}   {\normalsize}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize}
\setkomafont{paragraph}    {\normalsize}
\setkomafont{subparagraph} {\normalsize}

\addtokomafont{chapter}    {\centering\vspace*{-3em}}


\begin{document}

\chapter*{A}
\lipsum[1]

\section*{Aa}
\lipsum[1]

\clearpage

\chapter{B}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Bb}
\lipsum[1]

\clearpage

\chapter{C}
\lipsum[1]

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}` appears to have some effect on centering both lines.  Is this the appropriate method to center all chapter headings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the word Chapter all uppercase you can redefine `\chapterformat`:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\MakeUppercase{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}\thechapter\autodot
    \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}
```

To reduce the space between the two lines of the chapter title you can change the `innerskip` using e.g.

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  innerskip=-\parskip
]{chapter}
```

To center both lines of the chapter title use

```
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  parskip=half-,
  headings=twolinechapter
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{showframe}% show the page layout
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\MakeUppercase{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}\thechapter\autodot
    \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  innerskip=-\parskip
]{chapter}

\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[font=\normalsize]
  {chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{A}
\lipsum[1]
\section*{Aa}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{B}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Bb}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{C}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is similar to your past answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246411/koma-script-how-to-style-the-title-of-a-chapter).  Is this an updated response?  (Why did you ditch the `*` in `renewcommand` for centering?)  What are the appropriate methods for altering the vspace before the first line and/or after the second line? (You removed my \vspace from your answer.) Would this be something the typical user would be expected to realize?

Comment: _What are the appropriate methods for altering the vspace before the first line and/or after the second line? (You removed my \vspace from your answer.)_ I looked further in the the `\RedeclareSectionCommands` help.

Comment: @kando No this here is a different question. In the question you have linked is a rule drawn between the two lines of the chapter heading. Here only the skip between the prefix line and the title should be changed.

Comment: @kando To change the space before and after the chapter title (including the prefix line) change `beforeskip` and `afterskip` using `\RedeclareSectionCommand`. I did this also in the last update of the answer which you have linked.

Comment: Yep - see above comment: I looked further into `\RedeclareSectionCommands` in the \KOMA doc and saw the documentation for the answer. : j (Also, I added that rule - I liked it, but it definitely helped to see the code without the rule so I understood what did what.  Couldn't use the rule with the \mbox, so I ditched it. 
 Is that acceptable?)

Comment: How do I minimize the spacing between the heading and the text for non-chapter entries? `afterskip` <= 0em places the text inline with the heading.  All else has a sizeable space between the heading and the text (plus whatever else I enter in `afterskip`).

Comment: You have to use at least `afterskip=1sp minus 1sp` if you do not want an inline heading. So the space between a section heading and the following text is at least the same as between two normal paragraphs.

Comment: @kando, @esdd With KOMA-Script v3.26 (or later) you can also use `runin=false` to avoid inline headings. With this option you can use `afterskip=0pt` to have a zero skip or even `afterskip=-2pt` so have a real negative skip of 2pt.